# MySql search ranking with criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table named **customers** that keeps the customer's data

```
id  | fname  | lname  
--- | ------ | ------  
 1  | John   | Smith
 2  | Mike   | Bolton
 3  | Liz    | John
 4  | Mark   | Jobs
```

And i have another table named **calls** that keeps each call made to each customer.

```
id |     timestamp     | customer_id | campaign | answered |
 1 |2016-09-05 15:24:08|      1      |  2016-09 |     1    |
 2 |2016-09-05 15:20:08|      2      |  2016-09 |     1    |
 3 |2016-08-05 15:20:08|      2      |  2016-08 |     1    |
 4 |2016-08-05 13:20:08|      3      |  2016-08 |     1    |
 5 |2016-08-01 15:20:08|      3      |  2016-08 |     0    |
 5 |2016-08-01 12:20:08|      4      |  General |     1    |
```

Campaign **General** Doesn't count towards the calculations.

I need to get a list of customers ordered by ranking of **calling quality** based on each customer calling history.

This list is use to call the customers in order that:

- Hasn't been called on the actual calling campaign (ex.**2016-09**)
- Has fewer calls
- Best % answered (total calls answered / total calls made)

It should look something like this:

```
| id | fname  | lname | %ans | called actual campaign | total calls | rank |
|----|--------|-------|------|------------------------|-------------|------|
| 4  | Mark   | Jobs  | N/A  |          no            |      0      |   1  |
| 3  | Liz    | John  |  50  |          no            |      2      |   2  |
| 1  | John   | Smith | 100  |          yes           |      1      |   3  | No Show  
| 2  | Mike   | Bolton| 100  |          yes           |      2      |   4  | No Show
```

Please help me!

Comment: sqlfiddle it for us?

Comment: Pls also include what you have tried to solve the question yourself!

Comment: How do you define the **rank**?

Comment: @Drew here is the SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6accf/2

Comment: @1000111 fiddle delivered

Comment: @Shadow fiddle delived above. Thx Jota

Comment: I am just across the board upvoting questions that give fiddles for now on

Answer (score 1):

The query which counts for each customer total calls and answered calls for the specified campaign

```
select 
    c.id,
    count(*) as total_calls,
    sum(case when answered=1 then 1 else 0 end) as answered_calls
from customer c
     join calls cs on c.id=cs.customer_id
where cs.campaign='2016-09'
group by c.id
```

Then you can use the query above as a subquery to order

```
select sub.id, (@rank:=@rank+1) as rank
from (the subquery above) sub, (select @rank:=1)
order by 
  case when sub.total_calls=0 then 0 else 1,
  sub.total_calls, 
  sub.answered_calls*100/sub.total_calls
```

You can include any desired columns in the result query

Comment: i tried it but it give me an error. Every derived table must have its own alias
please check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6accf/2

Comment: @JotaD pls try to understand the error message and make the correction, it is not that difficult

Comment: @1000111 Thank you for the fiddle! That's really great to have the working example. Please post it as a correct working answer.

Comment: There were some syntax errors. I just fixed that. Nothing special I've done. And I don't know whether the query is correct or not. You may edit your answer. @StanislavL

Comment: @1000111 thanks for your help.
it as giving me a better understanding of this.
I updated the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee61f/16)

but now i need it the following ORDER CRITERIA.

1) NO SHOW CUSTOMERS THAT HAVE ANSWERED A CALL IN THIS CAMPAIGN
2) No calls at all in history
3) Less call and No Answered in  the campaign
4) More % answered calls (history answered / history calls to customer)
5) Order by Customers with cellphone numbers.